# Uncaught ReferenceError: AddAnime is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (AnimeSite.html:51)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a quick site with a list and I can't call a function:

function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    function AddAnime() {
        var newItem = document.getElementById("div")
        newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
        newItem.onClick = removeItem;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
    }
</script>
</head>
```

But when I call it with this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Anime" onclick="AddAnime();">
```

By the way, this is line 51
the error comes up.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: (A spelling checker is bound to pick nits: lower case 1st personal pronoun, contractions of " not" without apostrophe between n and t, even abbreviations like btw. without a "lower dot". Use one everywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the function outside of the onload scope:

```
<script>
function AddAnime() {
    var newItem = document.getElementById("div") newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
    newItem.onClick = removeItem;
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}
window.onload = function() {
    AddAnime();
}
</script>
```